# should I handle validations errors and messages in front end mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, frontend, mobile-application

then should clients update their app every time these texts has been changed?
I am new in mobile app and it is a little strange for me.
doesn't this make updating these texts hard? 
the most frequently change part of web app in my experience was front end. how should I handle these changes in mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pull the most important strings from a REST service, allowing you some degree of control. Another option may be to provide strings via Google Tag Manager - I have not yet used this feature of GTM myself, but I believe it is feasible (and it will handle caching for you). See the GTM documentation [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2644341#ValueCollection) and [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#get) for more details.